# my website is a disaster on IE 9 and less

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have been developping a website that works perfectly on all browsers, including IE 11, but as soon as I tried it on IE 8 and 9, it turned into an ugly unbelievable caos, where my css doesn't work, (at least most of it) and my javascript works terribly. here is my website: http://dev.ux-pm.com

as you can imagine, I am terrified by this fact, right before the deadline for my website, so please if anyone could give me the headlines of how to fix this I would be thankful.

I am using CSS3, HTML5 and jQuery 1.11.0

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Use HTML5 Shiv http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv it should help you in your case. It "repair" some of CSS things that IE 9 and less can't control

Comment: if you are using all HTML5 and CSS3 stuff then some might not work since lower versions of IE does not support them.. P.S. welcome to the world of IE hell..

Comment: your site is also horribad on tablets etc. I think you should fix that before ie9 and less porblems!

Comment: It shouldn't be working in fossilized browsers, your website contains too much new things that they don't know how to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a doctype
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.ux-pm.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

This will probably clear up quite a few issues with things looking wrong on older versions of IE but this won't necessarily fix everything. Validating is not a cure all but I do find that the more compliant the code is then the less likely bugs occur.

Comment: Lee it worked, all I needed to add was <!doctype html>. I don't know why this was the problem, but now it is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this plugin and see if the situation will become better.

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ (you need the media query with the sintax @media screen and ....)

http://selectivizr.com/

there is a lot of works anyway.
only half site is responsive and some responsive part broke the layout (eg top-menu)

Answer (score 0):

be carefully with the poland and france flag!

In your css file, you declare it:

```
#Poland{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:110px;
    left:404px;
    display:none;
}
```

but you must write Poland & France in lowercase like this:

```
#poland{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:110px;
    left:404px;
    display:none;
}

#france{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:128px;
    left:364px;
    display:none;
}
```